# How to populate missed dates in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

The task is to populate missing dates in the table. Dates should be in the middle of existing followed and previous dates.

Example of data in the table:

```
+----------+-------------------------+
| EntityID |       createdDate       |
+----------+-------------------------+
|    23964 | 2010-12-02 01:15:39.417 |
|    23965 | 2013-01-23 23:55:41.770 |
|    23966 |                         |
|    23967 |                         |
|    23968 |                         |
|    23969 |                         |
|    23970 | 2008-12-31 17:03:09.260 |
|    23971 | 2010-02-18 05:03:17.460 |
+----------+-------------------------+
```

To resolve this task I tried to execute folowing query:

```
UPDATE Entity
SET createdDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, (SELECT em.createdDate FROM Entity em WHERE em.EntityID = (EntityID - 1)))
WHERE createdDate IS NULL;
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you determine which date gets to be updated? And to which entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subselect in your update statement needs to qualify both EntityIDs - otherwise it's ambiguous. The below query will update each null date based on the nearest entity which has a date.

```
    UPDATE Entity
SET createdDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 
                    (SELECT TOP 1 entity.EntityID - em.EntityID FROM Entity em WHERE em.EntityID < (Entity.EntityID) AND em.createdDate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY EntityID DESC), 
                    (SELECT TOP 1 em.createdDate FROM Entity em WHERE em.EntityID < (Entity.EntityID) AND em.createdDate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY EntityID DESC))
WHERE createdDate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @id INT,
@create_date DATETIME

    DECLARE upadte_records CURSOR FOR SELECT EntityID, createdDate from Entity
    OPEN upadte_records
    FETCH NEXT FROM upadte_records INTO @id, @create_date
    WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
    BEGIN

            IF @create_date IS NULL
            BEGIN

                UPDATE Entity
                SET createdDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, (SELECT em.createdDate FROM Entity em WHERE em.EntityID = @id -1))
                WHERE EntityID = @id
            END


            FETCH NEXT FROM upadte_records INTO @id, @create_date
    END
    CLOSE upadte_records
    DEALLOCATE upadte_records
```